# Identifying equivalent sets in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Following is a sample of the records that I have in a table. `EntriesPerSet` column contains the number of records in the table for that `SET_ID`. I need to establish equivalence between rows belonging to different `SET_ID`s. Sets will be equivalent, if and only if they contain an equal number of entries per Set, and every entry has a corresponding entry in the other set (by checking values in `K1` & `K2`). In following case, `SET_IDs` 1 and 2 are equivalent.

```
SET_ID  K1  K2  EntriesPerSet
1   a   b   4
1   c   d   4
1   e   f   4
1   g   h   4
2   a   b   4
2   c   d   4
2   e   f   4
2   g   h   4
3   a   b   5
3   c   d   5
3   e   f   5
3   g   h   5
3   i   j   5
4   a   b   3
4   c   d   3
4   e   f   3
5   a   b   4
5   c   d   4
5   e   f   4
5   p   q   4
```

Please help me with how to do this. Thanks!

Comment: What would be the expected result in this case?

Comment: Are you comparing each set to every other set, or to a specific set?

Comment: The expected output in this case is 1 - 2 (since only 1 and 2 are equivalent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to know which pairs are equivalent, you can just use a common table expression to get all possible combinations, and an `INTERSECT` to figure out which of them overlap fully;

```
WITH cte AS (
 SELECT DISTINCT a.SET_ID aid, b.SET_ID bid, a.EntriesPerSet
 FROM mysets a
 JOIN mysets b ON a.EntriesPerSet = b.EntriesPerSet AND a.SET_ID < b.SET_ID
)
SELECT aid, bid FROM cte
WHERE EntriesPerSet = (
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT K1,K2 FROM mysets WHERE SET_ID=aid
  INTERSECT
  SELECT K1,K2 FROM mysets WHERE SET_ID=bid
 ) a
)
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f0566/1).

Comment: Just a quick question based on the output of this program. If a set has multiple sets that are equivalent, say 1 is equivalent to 2 and 3, i get the following output: 1-2, 1-3, 2-3. Is there a way to eliminate the rows like 2-3 within the common table expression itself? My ultimate goal is to identify unique buckets where i can put these sets (a bucket contains all equivalent sets).