# SQL Algorithm for grouping all "equivalent" strings

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an input table with two columns, each holding a string representing an id_number, and these columns are called id1 and id2.   The two id_numbers that appear as a pair in any given row are defined as being equivalent to each other.  If one of those id_numbers also appears in another row, then then all the strings in both rows are equivalent to eachother, etc.    The goal is to return a table with two columns, one containing all unique id_numbers and another identifying their grouping by equivalency.

Sample Data:
`

```
create table input_table (
id1 varchar(100),
id2 varchar(100)
)

insert into input_table(id1,id2)
values
('a','b'),
('b','c'),
('d','a'),
('a','b'),
('f','g'),
('f','k'),
('l','m')
```

Expected Output:

```
| Id | Grouping |
| a  | 1        |
| b  | 1        |
| c  | 1        |
| d  | 1        |
| f  | 2        |
| g  | 2        |
| k  | 2        |
| l  | 3        |
| m  | 3        |
```

To further explain the results:

- Row 1 tells us a=b so they are assigned to group 1
- Row 2 tells us b=c, since b is already in group 1, c is also assigned to group 1
- Row 3 tells us d=a, since a is already in group 1, d is also assigned to group 1
- Row 4 tells us a=b, which we already know so we don't need to do anything
- Row 5 tells us f=g, since neither are in an existing group, we assign them to group 2
- etc.

Comment: `<AcademicPedantMode>`SQL is not a language for implementing _algorithms_ because SQL is incapable of expressing a sequence of operations: it is capable of only describing a _single_ tabular query. Just sayin'`</AcademicPedantMode>`

Comment: _"The two id_numbers that appear as a pair in any given row are defined as being equivalent to each other."_ - what does that mean, exactly? (And using passive-voice does not help intelligiblity here...)

Comment: 1) Its extremely confusing that you talk extensively about id *numbers* which are in fact strings, not numbers. 2) Your logic doesn't make sense (to me at least) - I have no idea why g is ranked 2 for example, or l is ranked 3.

Comment: To answer most of the above:
id_numbers is a misnomer and i should have said id_strings...these are strings that represent a real world entity.  When i say equivalent, i mean they represent the same real world entity, so even though the strings are different, they represent the same thing.  I am trying to "group" strings together by the real world entity they represent.

Comment: To further explain the results:
Row 1 tells us a=b so they are assigned to group 1
Row 2 tells us b=c, since b is already in group 1, c is also assigned to group 1
Row 3 tells us d=a, since a is already in group 1, d is also assigned to group 1
Row 4 tells us a=b, which we already know so we dont need to do anything
Row 5 tells us f=g, since neither are in an existing group, we assign them to group 2
etc.

Comment: Rather than adding comments [edit] your question to provide clarification.

Comment: You should read a book on database design. What you have now is a very poor design, and as such is going to be a nightmare to do anything with at all.

Comment: This can help:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/23092901/11695049

Comment: I wrote an answer to a similar question a while ago: [How to find all connected subgraphs of an undirected graph](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35254260/4116017)

Answer (score 2):

Your table describes a nondirected graph, where the set (*distinct* values) of all `Id1` and `Id2` values over all tuples <sub>("rows")</sub> represent [nodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_(graph_theory)) and the tuples themselves represent the node's edges (as they connect - or link - these Id values in a relationship) - which means we can apply [graph-theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) techniques to solve your problem, which can be stated as finding [*disconnected components*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)) and assigning them an identifier) within your graph (as each *disconnected component* represents each set of connected nodes).

<sub>...with that formalism out of the way, I'll say I don't think it's necessarily correct to use the word "equivalent" or "equivalence": just because a binary relation (each of your tuples) is transitive (i.e. nondirected node edges are a transitive relation) it says nothing about what the nodes themselves represent, so I'm guessing you meant to say the `Id1`/`Id2` values represent things-that-are-equivalent in your problem-domain, which is fair, but in the context of my answer I'll refrain from using that term (not least because "set equivalence" is something else entirely)</sub>

[image]

ANYWAY...

---

### Step 1: Normalize your bad data:

Assuming that those `Id1`/`Id2` values are *comparable* values (as in: every value can be sorted *consistently and deterministically* by a *less-than* comparison), such as strings or integers, then *do that first* so we can generate a normalized representation of your data.

This normalized representation of your data would be the same as your current data, except that:

1. Every row's `Id1` value must be `<` (i.e. less-than) its `Id2` value.
2. There are no duplicate rows.

So if there's a row where `Id2 < Id1` you should swap the values, so `( 'd', 'a' )` becomes `( 'a', 'd' )`, and the duplicate `('a', 'b')` row would be removed.

This also means that every (disconnected) component in the graph we're representing now has a *minimum node* which we can treat as the (arbitrary) "root" of that component - which means we will have a *target* to look for from any node (but we don't know which values are minimums in each component yet, hang on...)

To aid identification, let's call the smallest value in a pair the *smol* value and the *big* value.

[image]

(You can do this step as another CTE step, but for clarity I'm using a
table-variable `@normalized`, like so):

```sql
DECLARE @horribleInputData TABLE (
    Id1 char(1) NOT NULL,
    Id2 char(1) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @horribleInputData ( Id1, Id2 ) VALUES
( 'a', 'b' ),
( 'b', 'c' ),
( 'd', 'a' ),
( 'a', 'b' ),
( 'f', 'g' ),
( 'f', 'k' ),
( 'l', 'm' );

--

DECLARE @normalized TABLE (
    Smol char(1) NOT NULL,
    Big  char(1) NOT NULL,

    INDEX IDX1 ( Smol ),
    INDEX IDX2 ( Big  ),

    CHECK ( Smol < Big )
);

INSERT INTO @normalized ( Smol, Big )
SELECT
    DISTINCT -- Exclude duplicate rows.
    CASE WHEN Id1 < Id2 THEN Id1 ELSE Id2 END AS Smol, -- Sort the values horizontally, not vertically.
    CASE WHEN Id1 < Id2 THEN Id2 ELSE Id1 END AS Big
FROM
    @horribleInputData
WHERE
    Id1 <> Id2;  -- Exclude zero-information rows.
```

After running the above, the `@normalized` table looks like this:

| Smol | Big |
| --- | --- |
| a | b |
| a | d |
| b | c |
| f | g |
| f | k |
| l | m |

### Step 2: Designate the minimum node as root in each disconnected component:

If we treat the node with the minimum-value as the "root" in a directed graph (or in this case, the minimum node in each *disconnected component*) then we can find connected nodes by finding a path from each node to that root. But what else defines a root? In this case, it would be a node with no "outgoing" references from `Smol` to `Big` - so we can simply take `@normalized` and [do an *anti-join* to itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Antijoin_.28.E2.96.B7.29) (i.e. for every `Smol`, see if that `Smol` is a `Big` to any other `Smol` - if none exist then that `Smol` is the `Smollest` - and is therefore a root:

```sql
SELECT
    DISTINCT
    l.Smol AS Smollest
FROM
    @normalized AS l
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @normalized AS r ON l.Smol = r.Big
WHERE
    r.Big IS NULL;
```

Which gives us this output:

| Smollest |
| --- |
| a |
| f |
| l |

...which tells us that there's 3 disconnected-components in this graph, and what those minimum nodes are.

### Step 3: the srsbsns part

Which means we can now try to trace a route from each node to a root using a recursive CTE - which is a technique in SQL to traverse
hierarchical directed graphs (either from top-to-bottom, or bottom-to-top), so it's a good thing we converted the data into a directed graph first.

For example:

- [SQL Server CTE and recursion example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274942/sql-server-cte-and-recursion-example)
- [SQL Server 2012 CTE Find Root or Top Parent of Hierarchical Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27050041/sql-server-2012-cte-find-root-or-top-parent-of-hierarchical-data)
- [Identifying equivalent sets in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23092901/identifying-equivalent-sets-in-sql-server)

Like so:

```sql
-- This `smolRoots` CTE is the same as the query from Step 2 above:
WITH smolRoots AS (
    
    SELECT
        DISTINCT
        l.Smol AS Smollest
    FROM
        -- This is an anti-join (a LEFT OUTER JOIN combined with a IS NULL predicate):
        @normalized AS l
        LEFT OUTER JOIN @normalized AS r ON l.Smol = r.Big
    WHERE
        r.Big IS NULL


),

-- Generate a simple flat list of every Id1/Id2 value:
everyNode AS (

    SELECT DISTINCT Smol AS Id FROM @normalized
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT Big  AS Id FROM @normalized
),

-- Now do the tree-walk, it's like a nature-walk but more math-y:
recursiveCte AS (
    
    -- Each root (Smol) value:
    SELECT
        CONVERT( char(1), NULL ) AS Smol,
        s.Smol AS Big,
        s.Smol AS SmolRoot,
        0      AS Depth
    FROM
        smolRoots AS s

    UNION ALL

    -- Then recurisvely UNION ALL (concatenate) all other rows that can be connected by their Smol-to-Big values:
    SELECT
        f.Smol,
        f.Big,
        r.SmolRoot,
        r.Depth + 1 AS Depth
        
    FROM
        @normalized AS f
        INNER JOIN recursiveCte AS r ON f.Smol = r.Big
)
```

The above `recursiveCte`, if evalated as-is, will return this output:

| Smol | Big | SmolRoot | Depth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | a | a | 0 |
| NULL | f | f | 0 |
| NULL | l | l | 0 |
| l | m | l | 1 |
| f | g | f | 1 |
| f | k | f | 1 |
| a | b | a | 1 |
| a | d | a | 1 |
| b | c | a | 2 |

Notice how for each row, each `Smol` and `Big` value is mapped to one of the 3 `SmolRoot` values identified in Step 2.

...so I hope you can now start to see how this works. But we're not done yet...

### Step 3.2: I lied about Step 3 being Step 3, it's really Step 3.1:

We still need to now *then query* the `recursiveCte`'s results to convert those `SmolRoot` values into unique identifiers for each disconnected component (i.e. each set) - so let's generate a new 1-based `int` value for each distinct value in `SmolRoot` - we can do this with `ROW_NUMBER()` but you could also use `GENERATE_SERIES` - and I'm sure other techniques exist to do this too:

```sql
WITH smolRoots AS ( /* same as above */ ),
everyNode AS ( /* same as above */ ),
recursiveCte AS ( /* same as above */ ),

numberForEachRoot AS ( -- Generate distinct numbers (from 1, 2, ...) for each SmolRoot number, i.e. a number for each disconnected-component or disjoint graph:
    
    SELECT
        SmolRoot,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY SmolRoot ) AS DisconnectedComponentNumber
    FROM
        recursiveCte AS r
    GROUP BY
        r.SmolRoot
```

And `numberForEachRoot` looks like this:

| SmolRoot | DisconnectedComponentNumber |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| f | 2 |
| l | 3 |

### Step 5: There is no Step 4

Now **ignore all of the above** and start over with that `everyNode` CTE that was tucked-away in *Step 2*: Take the `everyNode` CTE and `JOIN` it to `recursiveCte` and `numberForEachRoot` to get the actual output you're after:

```sql
WITH
smolRoots         AS ( /* same as above */ ),
everyNode         AS ( /* same as above */ ),
recursiveCte      AS ( /* same as above */ ),
numberForEachRoot AS ( /* same as above */ )
SELECT
    e.Id,
    n.DisconnectedComponentNumber
FROM
    everyNode AS e
    INNER JOIN recursiveCte AS r ON e.Id = r.Big
    INNER JOIN numberForEachRoot AS n ON r.SmolRoot = n.SmolRoot
ORDER BY
    e.Id;
```

Which gives us...

| Id | DisconnectedComponentNumber |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 1 |
| d | 1 |
| c | 1 |
| f | 2 |
| g | 2 |
| k | 2 |
| l | 3 |
| m | 3 |

This technique also works on graphs with cycles, though you might get duplicate output rows in that case, but adjusting the above query to filter those out is a trivial exercise left to the reader.

<sub>Also it seems I spent too much time on this answer, that means the Vyvanse is working tonight. And yup, it's just gone 4am where I am right now, good job, *me*. Now where's my Ambien gone?</sub>

### Step ∞: Just give me the solution I can copy-and-paste into my CS homework and/or [Nissan car firmware](https://www.theverge.com/tldr/2016/5/4/11593084/dont-get-busted-copying-code-from-stack-overflow)

Alright, you asked for it...

```sql
DECLARE @horribleInputData TABLE (
    Id1 char(1) NOT NULL,
    Id2 char(1) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @horribleInputData ( Id1, Id2 ) VALUES
('a','b'),
('b','c'),
('d','a'),
('a','b'),
('f','g'),
('f','k'),
('l','m'),
-- Also adding this to show that it works for cycles in graphs too:
( '0', '1' ),
( '1', '2' ),
( '2', '3' ),
( '3', '0' );

-------------

-- 1. Normalize to a table form that's easier to work with: given that transitivity exists, enforce `Id1 < Id2` so we can have a "direction" to look in.
-- This can be a CTE step instead of a TABLE too, if you dare. I'm curious what the execution plan would be in that case.

DECLARE @normalized TABLE (
    Smol char(1) NOT NULL,
    Big  char(1) NOT NULL,

    INDEX IDX1 ( Smol ),
    INDEX IDX2 ( Big  ),

    CHECK ( Smol < Big )
);

INSERT INTO @normalized ( Smol, Big )
SELECT
    DISTINCT
    CASE WHEN Id1 < Id2 THEN Id1 ELSE Id2 END AS Smol,
    CASE WHEN Id1 < Id2 THEN Id2 ELSE Id1 END AS Big
FROM
    @horribleInputData
WHERE
    Id1 <> Id2  -- Exclude zero-information rows.
ORDER BY
    Smol, -- Make it easier to read, interactively.
    Big;

/*
Smol    Big
----------
a   b
a   d
b   c
f   g
f   k
l   m
*/

-- Also, just gonna bury this in here and see what happens:
DECLARE @superImportantPart nvarchar(300) = CONVERT( nvarchar(300), 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
RAISERROR( @superImportantPart, /*severity:*/ 0, /*state:*/ 1 ) WITH NOWAIT;

-- Then trace a route from every Big to its smallest connected Smol.
-- Each Big sharing the same Smol is in the same connected graph, the set of distinct Smol nodes identifies each output set.


-- 1. Get all roots first: these will be `Smol` nodes that never appear in `Big`.
WITH smolRoots AS (
    
    SELECT
        DISTINCT
        l.Smol AS Smollest
    FROM
        @normalized AS l
        LEFT OUTER JOIN @normalized AS r ON l.Smol = r.Big
    WHERE
        r.Big IS NULL

/*
Smollest
-----
a
f
l
*/
),
everyNode AS (

    SELECT DISTINCT Smol AS Id FROM @normalized
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT Big AS Id FROM @normalized
),
-- The tree-walk:
recursiveCte AS (
    
    -- Each root (Smol) value:
    SELECT
        CONVERT( char(1), NULL ) AS Smol,
        s.Smollest AS Big,
        s.Smollest AS SmolRoot,
        0          AS Depth
    FROM
        smolRoots AS s

    UNION ALL

    -- Then the magic happens...
    SELECT
        n.Smol,
        n.Big,
        r.SmolRoot,
        r.Depth + 1 AS Depth
        
    FROM
        @normalized AS n
        INNER JOIN recursiveCte AS r ON n.Smol = r.Big

/*
Smol    Big SmolRoot    Depth
-----------------------------
NULL    a   a   0
NULL    f   f   0
NULL    l   l   0
l   m   l   1
f   g   f   1
f   k   f   1
a   b   a   1
a   d   a   1
b   c   a   2
*/
),
numberForEachRoot AS ( -- Generate distinct numbers (from 1, 2, ...) for each SmolRoot number, i.e. a number for each disconnected-component or disjoint graph:
    
    SELECT
        SmolRoot,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY SmolRoot ) AS DisconnectedComponentNumber
    FROM
        recursiveCte AS r
    GROUP BY
        r.SmolRoot

/*
SmolRoot    DisconnectedComponentNumber
-------------------
a   1
f   2
l   3
*/
)
-- Then ignore all of the above and start with `everyNode` and JOIN it to `recursiveCte` and `numberForEachRoot`:

SELECT
    e.Id,
    n.DisconnectedComponentNumber
FROM
    everyNode AS e
    INNER JOIN recursiveCte AS r ON e.Id = r.Big
    INNER JOIN numberForEachRoot AS n ON r.SmolRoot = n.SmolRoot
ORDER BY
    e.Id;

/*
Id  DisconnectedComponentNumber
a   1
f   2
l   3
m   3
g   2
k   2
b   1
d   1
c   1
*/
```

Comment: Very thorough explanation and nice touch with the `@superImportantPart` ;-) , but I'm afraid, your query doesn't always return correct result. I wrote an answer to a similar problem a while ago: [How to find all connected subgraphs of an undirected graph](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35254260/4116017). Try the sample data #2 in my answer with your query. With this input: `('b', 'f'),
('b', 'j'),
('d', 'f');` 
Your final query produces two DisconnectedComponentNumbers, while there should be 1, since all the nodes are connected.

Comment: Another example: `('a', 'z'),
('a', 'g'),
('z', 'h'),
('l', 'h')
`.  It should be one group. I think the problem comes from your approach to find "roots" - `it would be a node with no "outgoing" references from Smol to Big` - it seems that it is not that simple in general.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Yes, you are correct. I'm inclined to delete this answer as I don't want to give bad information out. From what I can tell, my approach only works in the case when nodes' labels are increasing with edge-distance from the root - and extending my approach to handle all cases ends-up with basically the same as your answer's code, except without `FOR XML PATH` now that we have `STRING_AGG` :)

Comment: It is up to you, but you've written a very nice explanation with illustrations. Maybe just add a note detailing in which cases this approach works and in which doesn't. I think it is important to show the limitations of a method, especially if it is not evident.